# Faradays law and rate of change of flux

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Consider a table with a uniform magnetic field of flux density $B$ coming directly out of it. The field lines are perpendicular to the the surface of the table, pointing up and out. Let a loop of wire enclosing area $A$ lie on the surface of the table, then flux through the loop is $AB$. Let me move the loop ALONG the table surface to another part of table in time $T$. Since the field is uniform the flux through the loop here is also $AB$. By Faradays law the induced emf is the rate of change of flux through loop which is $(AB-AB)/T = 0$. but how is this possible because the loop of wire which is the conductor clearly cuts the field lines as its moved along the surface of the table and hence there must be an induced emf right? What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case shown in the figure, where there is a magnetic field of strength B only on the right hand side of the line XX.

[image]

For the line segment EF, this cuts the magnetic field and the emf induced along this segment is $$\epsilon = \frac{d B}{d t} = B l v,$$ where $l$ is the length of the line segment EF and you can use [Fleming's right hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleming's_right-hand_rule) to determine the direction of the induced current which flows through the circuit.

After a short time, the line segment CD will cut the magnetic field. This will also have an emf induced along the segment. This will be of the same size as that along EF, but the current will flow in the opposite direction to that induced along EF. The net current will be zero.

Comment: thank you, got that. another question i had is assume instead of a loop i just move a wire, like just the wire EF. why does the emf turn out to be the same, given by Blv . in the case you gave we can find rate of change of flux by using change in area, that makes sense. But how would one calculate rate of change of flux for a wire which doesnt enclose an area, so what does flux AT a point mean for just a wire?

Answer (score 1):

There are charges moving and voltages building up but the integral of the EMF around the loop is still zero.

Comment: sorry i did not understand what you mean, can you please elaborate on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Start by considering a horizontal rectangular loop, WXYZ, being moved at speed $v$ in the direction of $\vec{WX}$, that is at right angles to the sides XY and ZW (each of length $l$, say). There will be emfs of magnitude $Blv$ induced in XY and ZW. These are in the directions of $\vec {XY}$ and $\vec{WZ}$ respectively. Although in the same direction in space, in terms of the circuit WXYZ, they are in opposite senses. [Seen from above the emf in XY is clockwise and that in WZ is anticlockwise.] So they cancel to zero.

**Note 1**

The directions I've given for the emfs in XY and ZW can be checked using Fleming's Right Hand Generator Rule. More fundamentally, the magnitude and direction of the emfs can be found by applying the magnetic Lorentz force law to the free electrons, as these move with the wires. For example,
$$\mathscr E_{XY} = \text{Work done per unit charge on electron going X to Y} =\frac 1{-e}(-e)(\vec v \times \vec B).\vec{XY}$$
$$\text{that is}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathscr E_{XY}=(\vec v \times \vec B).\vec{XY}.$$

**Note 2**

The method just used for the rectangular loop can be generalised to show that the total emf is zero around any shape of planar loop. To do this note that, in this set-up, $\vec v \times \vec B$ is a vector of magnitude $Bv$ and of fixed direction ($\hat x$, say) in the plane of the loop and at right angles to $\vec v$. For any short increment, $d\vec s$, of the loop perimeter the induced emf is
$$d\mathscr E=(\vec v \times \vec B).d\vec{s}=Bv\hat x.d\vec s=Bv\ dx$$
$\hat x.d\vec s$ is the component, $dx$, of $d\vec s$ in the fixed direction $\hat x$, and over the complete loop, $\int dx=\Delta x=0$, that is the $x$ components of the loop increments will sum to zero.

**Note 3**

Arguably the most elegant way of showing that the cutting of flux gives the same emf as rate of change of flux through the loop, zero in this case, is to show that it is true in general. We can use the flux-cutting equation derived earlier for the emf induced in an element XY of the loop
$$\mathscr E_{XY}=(\vec v \times \vec B).\vec{XY}.$$
Now, though, we don't insist that $v$ is the same for each element. We may re-arrange the scalar triple product, making the equation:
$$\mathscr E_{XY}=(\vec {XY} \times \vec v).\vec B=\frac{d\vec A}{dt}.\vec B.$$
Here, $\frac{d\vec A}{dt}= \vec {XY} \times \vec v$ is the rate of addition to the loop area due to the motion of XY, and $\frac{d\vec A}{dt}.\vec B$ is the rate at which flux through the loop increases due to the motion of XY. Adding the contributions from flux-cutting by all the increments, we get the total rate of change of flux through the loop.